# Does "Email Quote" leave any artifacts? Possible to query OutgoingEmail?

Tags: trigger, soql, email, quote

I am digging around trying to figure out what sort of options we have to trigger an event when someone executes the <kbd>Email Quote</kbd> standard action on the `Quote` object. I poked around the child relationships using this script:

```
for (ChildRelationship relation : SObjectType.Quote.getChildRelationships())
    system.debug(relation);
```

The only relationship that has Email in the name is:

> Schema.ChildRelationship[
>   getChildSObject=OutgoingEmail;
>   getField=RelatedToId;
>   getJunctionIdListNames=();
>   getRelationshipName=null;
>   isCascadeDelete=false;
>   isDeprecatedAndHidden=false;
>   isRestrictedDelete=false;
>   ]

So I gathered up some fields for this object using the following script:

```
for (SObjectField field : SObjectType.OutgoingEmail.fields.getMap().values())
    system.debug(field);
```

I tried the below query:

```
SELECT RelatedToId, WhoId, HtmlBody, ToAddress
FROM OutgoingEmail WHERE RelatedToId = '0Q0...'
```

But no matter what query I run, I get this error:

> System.ExternalObjectException: data.api.DataSourceUnsupportedQueryException: This query is not supported on the OutgoingEmail object.

At this point I'm just trying to figure out if the <kbd>Email Quote</kbd> action actually creates a record in the `OutgoingEmail` object. **Is there any supported way to query this object? Does this action leave any other artifacts which can be detected or triggered on?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this same issue a while back and didn't manage to resolve it without creating a custom button which triggered some apex, essentially building the quote using the template id and quote id then using some apex to attach the quote to the required email address and parentId and send it out.

It may not be exactly what you are after but here is the code to build the quote:

```
//Id of Quote record.
String QuoteID = '0Q0XXXXXXXXXXX';

//Id of quote Template
String templateID = '0EHXXXXXXXXX';

//This Url create the pdf for quote
String quoteUrl = '/quote/quoteTemplateDataViewer.apexp?id=';

quoteUrl +=QuoteID;

quoteUrl +='&headerHeight=190&footerHeight=188&summlid=';

quoteUrl +=templateID ;

quoteUrl +='#toolbar=1&navpanes=0&zoom=90';

//Create pdf content
PageReference pg = new PageReference(quoteUrl) ;

//Document object of quote which hold the quote pdf
QuoteDocument quotedoc = new QuoteDocument(); 

//Get the content of Pdf.
Blob b = pg.getContentAsPDF() ;

//content assign to document
quotedoc.Document = b;

//assign quote id where pdf should attach
quotedoc.QuoteId = QuoteID ;

//insert the quotdoc
 insert quotedoc;
```

Comment: How exactly did you get the `SummaryLayout` Id? Queries against this object are unsupported.

Comment: Do you know how to obtain the header and footer height, or are they derived by experiment?

Comment: @DavidReed I derived them by experiment, that looks to be the standard

Comment: @AdrianLarson Did you managed to figure out the summary layout Id?